# How to conditionally subscribe inside an observable, wait for response and return the complete result?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, twilio

I have an `Observable` from a `Promise` like so (I am using strict Typescript):

```
let foo: Subscription = from(channel.getMessages).pipe(flatMap((data: any) => data.items))

// then I subscribe to it like this
foo.subscribe((val: any) => console.log(val))
```

I need to pipe `flatMap` in because the `channel` object has an `items` array property that holds all the *text* messages. This would be pretty straightforward, however some messages are of type *media* and in those cases I have to do another request with the `media.getContentUrl` (which is also a `Promise`). So in this case I have to get back the `url` of the *media* not the *text* message body.

So far I tried doing something like:

```
let foo = from(channel.getMessages)
            .pipe(
              flatMap(data => data.items), 
              map((item: any) => {
                if (item.type === 'media') {
                  return from(item.media.getContentUrl).subscribe((val: any) => val);
                }
                return item.body;
              })
            );
```

This returns the `item.body` correctly but gives an error when the message is type *media*: `TypeError: You provided 'function getContentUrl(): ... where stream was expected`

My goal is to have an observable in which I am getting messages but when the message type is *media* I send another request, **wait** for it and I get everything back together so for example after  I get back the data my array would look like this:

```
messages = [
  'foo',
  'bar',
  'http://example.com/img1.jpg',
  'baz',
  'http://example.com/img2.jpg'
]
```

The main problem I'm facing in Reactive thinking way is: how do you set up an observable that *may* have to have another observable (or a simple request) inside of it based on some condition?
How would you do this in an elegant reactive manner?

Comment: Did you tried to put `return of(item.body)` instead of `return item.body`?

Comment: Sorry that should have been `return of(item.body)`. Corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `map` to `flatMap` and do not `subscribe` inside operators, `flatMap` will execute inner observable for you

```
          flatMap(data => data.items), 
          flatMap((item: any) => {
            return (item.type === 'media')? from(item.media.getContentUrl()):
            of(item.body);
          })
```

there is also an `iif` operator available 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/iif.html

but personally i stick with native javascript